# MULE ESB results from database as JSON array

Tags: json, mule, esb

I am using MULE ESB and have a flow which is designed to pull all the results out of the Mysql Database and place all the results in one JSON file. However I am gettign the results as separate JSON files, not one JSON file (which is the desired outcome)

Here is my config file

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mysql.properties,classpath:smtp.properties" />
<smtp:connector name="emailConnector" fromAddress="${smtp.from}" subject="${smtp.subject}" doc:name="SMTP" validateConnections="true"/>
<jdbc-ee:connector name="jdbcConnector" dataSource-ref="MySQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="false"  queryTimeout="10" pollingFrequency="10000" doc:name="JDBC"> 
    <jdbc-ee:query key="Users" value="SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id ASC"></jdbc-ee:query>  
</jdbc-ee:connector>
<jdbc-ee:mysql-data-source name="MySQL_Data_Source" user="${mysql.user}" password="${mysql.password}" url="${mysql.url}" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MySQL Data Source"></jdbc-ee:mysql-data-source>
<flow name="flows1Flow1" > 
    <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint queryKey="Users" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="JDBC"></jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>

    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\New folder" doc:name="File" responseTimeout="10000"></file:outbound-endpoint>  
</flow>
```

Comment: What is your expected JSON ?? and what JSON are you getting ?

Comment: The JSON I am getting is: {"data":"spongebob squarepants","id":11} Expected  "cartoonsl": [
                            "spongebob squarepants",
                            "justice league"
                             ],

Comment: Pls edit your question with both the JSON data .. pls don't put in comment ... it's difficult to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Mule are you using? the jdbc connector you are using is deprecated in 3.5+. I was able to get the result you are expecting using the config below in 3.7.1:

```
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost"
    port="" user="" database="test" pass="" doc:name="MySQL Configuration" />

<flow name="flows1Flow1">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM test.people]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    </poll>

    <json:object-to-json-transformer
        doc:name="Object to JSON" />

    <logger level="ERROR" message="#[payload]" doc:name="Logger" />

    <file:outbound-endpoint path="./people"
        doc:name="File" responseTimeout="10000" />
</flow>
```

HTH